# What does `wildignore` actually do and what functions/tools respect it?

Tags: vimrc

```
                                                'wildignore' 'wig'
'wildignore' 'wig'      string  (default "")
                        global
                        {not available when compiled without the +wildignore
                        feature}
        A list of file patterns.  A file that matches with one of these
        patterns is ignored when expanding wildcards, completing file or
        directory names, and influences the result of expand(), glob() and
        globpath() unless a flag is passed to disable this.
        The pattern is used like with :autocmd, see autocmd-patterns.
        Also see 'suffixes'.
        Example:
                :set wildignore=*.o,*.obj
        The use of :set+= and :set-= is preferred when adding or removing
        a pattern from the list.  This avoids problems when a future version
        uses another default.
```

It seems that this documentation would indicate that `wildignore` will cause functions like glob/expand/globpath to ignore the patterns in this variable.

Currently this is my setting:

```
wildignore=*.o,*.a,*.so,*.pyc,*.swp,.git/,*.class,*/target/*,.idea/
```

If I use glob:

```
:echo glob(".gi*")
.git
.gitignore
```

This is not what I'd expect from the documentation.

However, if I do:

```
:edit .gi<TAB>
```

It will instantly complete to `.gitignore` and subsequent double taps of  will not cycle to `.git`.  So it seems that `:edit` uses wildignore as I'd expect.

Comment: Just a thought, but shouldnt wildignore affect only wildmenu responses, and maybe some other plugins that use it, but not a vanilla function such as glob? I still agree the doc is off if this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

One of the items in your `'wildignore'` list is `.git/`. I think you'll get the behavior you're looking for if you change it to `.git,.git/*`.

But to understand what's going on here, I think you have highlighted a behavioral difference between the way completion and functions like `glob()` work. My guess is that the functions don't identify a directory called `.git` as a match for the pattern `.git/` because the trailing slash isn't actually part of the name. However, for tab completion, the trailing slash is often inserted for directories as a convenience. Maybe for completion, the trailing slash is added to the input before it gets filtered by the pattern.